# JQUERY response not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

I have an ajax that sends an email with some information, and then responds sent or notsent, my problem is that i dont know why the if after the .done for ajax should do something if the respond is "sent" according to the inspector the respond is sent but it always goes to the else in my if sention, and i have no idea why, the email is sent and everything but i just cant understand why always goes to the else.

my jquery is like this:

```
function Send()
{
    var nom = $('#name').val();
    var ape = $('#lastname').val();
    var occ = $('#occupation').val();
    var dep = $('#department').val();
    var dob = $('#datob').val();
    var bdp = $('#place').val();
    var add = $('#address').val();
    var cid = $('#cidnumber').val();
    var pho = $('#phone').val();
    var pem = $('#mail').val();
    var sta = $('#station').val();
    if(bdp == '' || add == '' || cid == '' || pho == '' || pem == '')
    {
        swal("Ooops!", "All the information MUST be filled, Please check!.", "error");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#myModalEmail').modal('toggle');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'AccionesPHP.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {funcion:'SendIdMail',name:nom,lastname:ape,occupation:occ,department:dep,dob:dob,place:bdp,address:add,companyid:cid,phone:pho,mail:pem,station:sta}
        })

        .done(function(respuesta){
            if(respuesta == "sent")
            {
                $('#myModalEmail').modal('hide');
                swal("Success!", "Your Card Request has been sent successfuly.", "success");
                LoadData();
            }
            else
            {
                swal("Ooops!", "This is embarrasing, we have a proble could you try later, Error!.", "error");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my PHP is like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $occupation = $_POST['occupation'];
        $department = $_POST['department'];
        $dob = $_POST['dob'];
        $place = $_POST['place'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $companyid = $_POST['companyid'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $mail = $_POST['mail'];
        $station = $_POST['station'];
        //ENVIO DE MAIL PARA DAVID WING

        $mensaje = '<html>'; 
        $mensaje .= '<body>';
        $mensaje .= '<h3> New Company Identification Card Request </h3>';
        $mensaje .= '<div><p> The information for the Card request is below:</p>';
        $mensaje .= '<label>Name</label>';
        $mensaje .= '<input type="text" value="'. $name .'" disabled><br<br>';
        $mensaje .= '<label>Last Name</label>';
        $mensaje .= '<input type="text" value="'. $lastname .'" disabled><br<br>';
        $mensaje .= '<label>Occupation</label>';
        $mensaje .= '<input type="text" value="'. $occupation .'" disabled><br<br>'; 
        $mensaje .= '<label>Depatment</label>';
        $mensaje .= '<input type="text" value="'. $department .'" disabled><br<br>'; 
        $mensaje .= '<label>Date of Birth</label>';
        $mensaje .= '<input type="text" value="'. $dob .'" disabled><br<br>';
        $mensaje .= '<label>Birth Place</label>';
        $mensaje .= '<input type="text" value="'. $place .'" disabled><br<br>';
        $mensaje .= '<label>Address</label>';
        $mensaje .= '<input type="text" value="'. $address .'" disabled><br<br>';
        $mensaje .= '<label>Company ID</label>';
        $mensaje .= '<input type="text" value="'. $companyid .'" disabled><br<br>';
        $mensaje .= '<label>Phone</label>';
        $mensaje .= '<input type="text" value="'. $phone .'" disabled><br<br>';
        $mensaje .= '<label>Personal e-mail</label>';
        $mensaje .= '<input type="text" value="'. $mail .'" disabled><br<br>';
        $mensaje .= '<label>Station</label>';
        $mensaje .= '<input type="text" value="'. $station .'" disabled><br<br>';
        $mensaje .= '</body> </html>';

        $para = 'gjmm1711@gmail.com';
        $titulo = 'New Company Identification Card Request';
        $cabeceras = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $cabeceras .='From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        if(mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras))
        {
            print "sent";
        }
        else
        {
            print "notsent";
        }

        break;
```

Comment: I can't find where in your code you send in the parameter "respuesta"?

Comment: Does your email get sent?

Comment: I didn't see your full php-source, but, is it important thing :  " funcion:'SendIdMail' ", mistype in parameter-name ?
Oh.. nvm.. it's spanish lang :)

Comment: Sorry i added answer instead of comment =/

Comment: if(respuesta.trim() == "sent") - if this changes will works, you have an extra spaces before or after  "sent".

Comment: Do not print/echo your respond value. I assume you create a function/class there. so what you need is set respond variable like "status" and return the value of that variable like return $status. That way your ajax will wait for your function to return a response.

Comment: What is there in php after the `break` ?

Comment: So i tried adding trim and it worked, i have no idea where is the space but looks like it was that... thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the email is sent, the 'respuesta' is where i get the data from php which should be "sent" or "notsent" which comes from the if (mail ()) if it's true returns "sent" which is working according to the inspector i get "sent" as answer but still when i do if (respuesta=="sent")
Do something

Else
Do something

Idk why it always go to else if the answer from php is "sent"

Comment: can it be, that you have extra characters or spaces before of after string? something like extra \r\n after closing "?>" ?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use Promise for this since your ajax query is querying another server. This should work with a bit of tweaking four your needs.

Like this;

```
   function send_mail(nom,ape,occ, ...){
         return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'AccionesPHP.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data
{'name':nom,'lastname':ape,'occupation':occ,'department':dep,'dob':dob,'place':bdp,'address':add,'companyid':cid,'phone':pho,'mail':pem,'station':sta},
            success: function (data, status) {
                resolve(data);
                return;
            },
            error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
                return;
            }
        }); 
     });
    }
```

Now your ajax event handler

```
      $( document ).ready(function() {
         $('#myModalEmail').modal('toggle' , function (event) {
                event.preventDefault(event);

                send_mail().then(function (response) {
                 respuesata = response;

 if(respuesta == "sent")
            {
                $('#myModalEmail').modal('hide');
                swal("Success!", "Your Card Request has been sent successfuly.", "success");
                LoadData();
            }
            else
            {
                swal("Ooops!", "This is embarrasing, we have a proble could you try later, Error!.", "error");
            }

    //Check your data here

                }, function (error) {
                    console.error("Échec !", error);
                    return;
                });
            });
            });
```

Comment: This way your jquery will wait for the response before it finishes.